# Vue.js subcomponent not reacting under nested SVG

Tags: vue.js, svg, colors

I have an SVG diagram in a Vue.js template with nested drawn circles symbolizing doors. When the doors are OPEN the stroke/fill color should be GREEN; & when CLOSED the stroke/fill color should be RED.  When my R/T data arrives (i.e. to SignalR client plug-in). I need to set the state & compute the colors, which I am doing, but the colors are not getting redrawn. Any suggestions? I am using Vue.js 2.9.6.
Thank you

I have tried computed properties as well as watches. The data() fields are updating but the bound colors are not reacting.

In the template

```
    <div class="VcSchematicAccessControlRedundantImg" >            

        <svg :width="widthImg" :height="heightImg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >       
            <image xlink:href="static/img/PNID_AccessControl_Redundant.svg" height="100%" width="100%" />

        <circle cx="288.0"  cy="504.0"  r="9" stroke-width="3" :stroke="r2aColor"  :fill="r2aColor"  />    
        <circle cx="670.0"  cy="530.0"  r="9" stroke-width="3" :stroke="r2bColor"  :fill="r2bColor"  />
        <circle cx="352.0"  cy="874.0"  r="9" stroke-width="3" :stroke="r3Color"   :fill="r3Color"   />
        <circle cx="949.0"  cy="546.0"  r="9" stroke-width="3" :stroke="r7Color"   :fill="r7Color"   />
        <circle cx="565.7"  cy="580.0"  r="9" stroke-width="3" :stroke="r8Color"   :fill="r8Color"   />
        <circle cx="430.0"  cy="455.7"  r="9" stroke-width="3" :stroke="r9Color"   :fill="r9Color"   />            



        </svg>            


    </div>
```

I need to get the drawing to rerender every update cycle with data from SignalR Client. Note: my SignalR Client & Vue.js plug-in are working fine. Something seems to be amiss with Vue.js' reactivity here.

Comment: I got this working. I had a side-effect in my data plug-in. I also rewrote to use a single object for loading of data & for the watch. This worked much better.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding key to component that you want redrawn ? With some properties you want to force redraw and changing the key o that component. For example

```
  <template>
    <div :key="updateCounter" >
      {{someContent}}
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    export default {

    data() {
      return {
        updateCounter: 0
      };
    },
    computed: {
      valueToWatch() {some dynamic value}
    },
    watch: {
      valueToWatch() {
        this.updateCounter += 1 
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Here is great article about forcefully rerendering
[The correct way to force Vue to re-render a component](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render)

Comment: No. This doesn't work. I tried that with flipping a string between '0' & '1', but no change. The initial render is fine only. I also tried the not-so-pretty v-if (& separating 'red' & 'green', & that didn't work either. I also tried the this.$forceUpdate(). Nothing is working in this scenario.